# Wordpress advanced custom fields inline background

Tags: php, wordpress

Having trouble linking a background image using inline-css with Advanced Custom Fields.

Here's where I'm at:

HTML

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home Page
*/

//Advanced Custom Fields
$header_image                =  get_field('header_image');
$header_image_text           =  get_field('header_image_text');

get_header(); ?>

...

<div class="carousel-inner">

  <?php if( !empty($header_image) ) : ?>
    <div class="item active" style="background: url( <?php echo $header_image['url']; ?> )">
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if( !empty($header_image_text) ) : ?>
    <div class="container"><img src="<?php echo $header_image_text['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $header_image_text['alt']; ?>"></div>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>

...
```

Within my Field Settings, the `$header_image` and `$header_image_text`  Return Value is set to Image Object.

Thanks.

**Solution:**

Used Maulik patel's answer but changed `$header_image_new` value to `''.$header_image["url"].'';`

Comment: Can you please show us image object too?

Comment: Can you please do like this `print_r($header_image); print_r($header_image_text); die;` and let me know what it returns?

Comment: Could you show us the rest of the CSS style code you've set for the `.item.active` element? Additionally you should try using the second parameter (post ID) of the `get_field` function. Just to make sure it is loading fields for the correct post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home Page
*/

//Advanced Custom Fields
$header_image                =  get_field('header_image');
$header_image_text           =  get_field('header_image_text');
$header_image_new='"'.$header_image["url"].'"';
get_header(); ?>

...

<div class="carousel-inner">

  <?php if( !empty($header_image) ) : ?>
    <div class="item active" style="background: url( <?php echo $header_image_new; ?> )">
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if( !empty($header_image_text) ) : ?>
    <div class="container"><img src="<?php echo $header_image_text['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $header_image_text['alt']; ?>"></div>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```